# can i get a free ssl certificate for a website that has a domain name but is forwarded to my personal laptop?

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

This is my first time getting a node backend up and running out there on the web. I bought myself a domain name from godaddy.com which is frogtoprincejs.io. It gets redirected to my personal macOS laptop with port 80 open. i've been trying to generate an ssl with lets encrypt that is a free ssl certificate provider but no go. I don't know if it's my server or the setup alone is not do able. So I would like to know if its even possible to get a free ssl certificate for a website that has a registered domain name but redirects it to my personal laptop's ip. 
NOTE: this is all educational i am trying to learn how to setup a secure website

Comment: If you officially have the domain name, and it's pointing to a working server, there should be a way to set it up. The location of the hardware shouldn't be a limiting factor. (Don't know much about this, but don't you also need at least port 443 open? not sure if Lets Encrypt will fix it / notify you)

Comment: I am trying to generate a certificate first from lets encrypt via cert bot ssl generator which does a test on my server to see if its valid for the ssl.

Comment: One thing to note is that depending on your internet provider you may not be able to host a website (legally). For example, before you can host a website using Comcast you need a business plan, using a personal plan would be against their terms of service. This is one of many reasons to use an online hosting service.

Comment: Call your ISP and ask if the port 80 and 443 are blocked or not (inbound). If yes... Ask how much to unblock. And look the competitors. --- **From personal experience**: You better rent a server. Limitations tied to YOUR personnal internet access (for reasonable price) is not enough to serve a website. For the quarter of what it would cost to upgrade your internet connection at home, you can have a super stable always running server.

Comment: Then... If you have additionnal questions, those may be best served on https://serverfault.com/